# How do you say "I have begun studying Japanese"?

Tags: grammar

How do you say "I have begun studying Japanese"?

I have memorized all of the hiragana characters along with some grammar rules.

I have made sentences on my own but I can't seem to get this right.
I have tried this

> にほんごべんきょうはじぇました

It sounds weird to me but I'm not completely sure if this is right or wrong

If possible, please write it in Romaji along with hiragana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt:

> にほんごべんきょうはじぇました

Firstly, I'm assuming はじぇました was a typo for はじ**め**ました. Secondly, you're missing a few particles. If you studied some grammar you should become familiar at an early stage with the object marking particle を and the possessive particle の.

Using these you could say:

> にほんご**の**べんきょう**を**はじめました。
>   nihongo no benkyou wo hajimemashita.

where the whole of にほんごのべんきょう is the object of the verb はじめました i.e. the thing that was started.

When you see の the thing before の normally describes the thing after. So, what kind of study (べんきょう) is it? It's Japanese study, にほんごのべんきょう. Here べんきょう is used as a noun.

The verb はじめる also attaches to the masu-stem of verbs, so you could use "study" as a verb rather than a noun as we did above. The verb is べんきょうする. The masu-stem of する is し. So "started to study" is べんきょうしはじめました。 The object is now simply the thing we are studying, which is Japanese. So we get:

> にほんご**を**べんきょうしはじめました。
>   nihongo wo benkyou shi-hajimemashita.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. You have cleared a lot of things and fixed my mistakes.

Comment: I tried typing "I have loved Japanese since a long time" with the proper particles this time and If possible, please review it and tell me if it's correct or not.

むかしからにほんごをすきった

Comment: 「ずっとまえからにほんごがすきでした」or maybe 「むかしからにほんごがすきでした」とか。。。　すき is a na-adjective, and conjugates to すきだ, すきです, すきな... (btw "since a long time" ってあってんの？)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I think I typed すきった wrong. I meant すきだった. 

And is it possible to add the Particle wo/o instead of ga at にほんごを. Since wo/o marks the object which is にほんご which receives the action of the verb すきだった.

Comment: @Chocolate In this case, it should be "since a long time ago" or "for a long time".

Comment: My final one is "むかしからにほんごをすきだった" Mukashikara nihongo o Sukidatta.

The wo/o Is put there because the object is Nihongo, and it's receiving the action of the verb Sukidatta (I loved)

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Would 勉強するようになった be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: @user1602 That doesn't seem quite right to me, but I'm not sure. I think it would be worth asking a new question on はじめる versus ようになる.

Comment: To my knowledge 連用形始める is to start doing something at the moment and implies that the action will not be continuing for a long time. 連体形ようになった on the other hand implies that the action started in general and will be continuing for a long time.